# Is there a way to pass an object as a lambda function so the dependent class accesses through this function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a manager class which initializes child classes with some dependencies. The problem with the dependencies is that in some instances a new object for them is created. This particular part is out of my control and cannot be updated to reuse the same reference.

My manager class receives an event which contains the new object and I update my manager to use that. The same dependency is used in the child classes as well and now I have to update them there as well. I want to check if there's a way through which I can write a lambda function in my manager class and pass that function to the child classes such that the reference to the object in child classes is always the latest one? Something that can prevent the hassle of maintaining/updating references in all the classes.

I tried adding a lambda function and passing it to the child classes but it's not allowing me to call the functions of the value returned by the lambda function. Error: `Property '....' does not exist on type '() =>....'` and `Property '....' does not exist on type '(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]) => any'`

Following is the code for the lambda that I wrote:

```
private dep1 = (): Dep1 => {
    return this._dep1Object;
  };
```

I'm passing dep1 directly to the child classes and tried using it like this:

```
dep1.METHOD_REFERENCE
dep1.call().METHOD_REFERENCE
```

Comment: What issue you get when try to call the functions?

Comment: Updated the question to include the error: Property '....' does not exist on type '() =>....'

Comment: From the error it seems you are not calling the function in the child class to get the return object and then access properties on the returned object but you are trying to access properties directly on the function. Could you confirm that you are doing something like "parentFunction().propertyName"?
Could you put the code snippet as well about how you define lambda, how you pass it to child and then how you use it in the child?

Comment: Added the two ways I tried.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  If you make it easy for others to reproduce the problem, you're more likely to get a tested and useful answer.